# JFrame window not popping up?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm pretty new to java, and I'm trying to make a simple JFrame application, although when I click run, nothing displays.  I have followed some youtube tutorials, and i've pretty much copied and pasted this code, although i'm not sure why it works for the youtube demonstration, and not mine.  Some help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Game extends JFrame{
    private JButton clicker;
    private int clicks = 0;

    public Game(){
        createView();

        setTitle("Game");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(true);
    }

    private void createView(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        clicker = new JButton("Here's a jbutton");

        clicker.addActionListener(new Button());

        panel.add(clicker);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game().setVisible(true);
    }

    private class Button implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            clicks += 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: Works fine for me. What IDE?  Have you tried performing a clean & build?

Comment: Same here -- this code runs. No error can be reproduced.

Comment: This probably isn't the cause of your issue, but you should be submitting your Swing code to the event dispatch thread.

Comment: I don't know what is your OS, but the window may be hidden by yout IDE's window.
Check with your task manager, or alt tab. Your window must be there :-)